# How to insert price based on checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form where I calculate the price based on the checkboxes checked. But I am having trouble as its not updating the final price correctly. I did some jQuery coding but it's not functioning properly. How can I debug the code and fix it?

```
//Price Calculator
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  function Calculator(){
    let totalAmount = 0;
    if($('input[datasource=service_0]').is(':checked')){  // First Checkbox targeted using datasource attribute
      totalAmount = 395;
      return totalAmount;
    }else if($('input[datasource=service_1]').is(':checked')){   // First Checkbox targeted using datasource attribute
      totalAmount = 392;
      return totalAmount;
    }else if ($("input[datasource=service_0]:checked,input[datasource=service_1]:checked").length == 2) {
      totalAmount = 397;
      return totalAmount;
    }
  }
  //Insert Updated Amount to Budget field
  $("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function(){
    if ($("input[datasource=service_0]:checked,input[datasource=service_1]:checked").length == 2){
      $("input[name=wpcf-book-amount]").val(Calculator());
    } else{
      $("input[name=wpcf-book-amount]").val(Calculator());
    }
  })
  
})
```

```
<div class="extra-services">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="wpcf-additional-services[]" data-value="5" id="wpcf-fields-checkboxes-option-d41b805f6cbf1d0ab6ee12b8dda8b47d-1" datasource="service_0">
            <label for="wpcf-additional-services">Cot (EUR 5)</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="wpcf-additional-services[]" data-value="2" id="wpcf-fields-checkboxes-option-d41b805f6cbf1d0ab6ee12b8dda8b47d-1" datasource="service_1">
            <label for="wpcf-additional-services">BABY CHAIR (EUR 2)</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <input type="text" name="wpcf-booking-amount" id="booking_field" placeholder="Booking Amount (System Generated)" readonly>
</div>
```

[Form containing the fields responsible to calculate the booking amount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icciY.png)

Comment: Please add the html code.

Comment: @user17517503 It's a WordPress-based dynamically generated form that I can't copy. But here is the overall HTML code structure that is generated dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <input type="checkbox"  id="1st" onclick="ge()"  value=500>
  <label for="1st"> I have a bike</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox"  id="2nd" onclick ="ye()" value=200>
  <label for="2nd"> I have a car</label>

<input type="number" id="here" value="0">
        <script>
        var amt = 0;
        var st = document.getElementById("1st");
        var nd = document.getElementById("2nd");
        var num = document.getElementById("here");
        function ge() {
            
            
            if(st.checked == true ){
                var g =  parseInt(st.value);
            amt = amt + g;
            num.value = amt ;
            } 
            else{
                
                amt = amt - parseInt(st.value);
                num.value = amt;
                
            }
        }
        function ye() {
            if(nd.checked == true){
                var g =  parseInt(nd.value);
            amt = amt + g;
            num.value = amt ;
            }
            else{
                amt = amt - parseInt(nd.value);
                num.value = amt;
            }
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here you go if it's only for two checkbox this will work, for live demo [click here](https://codepen.io/gauntletww/pen/VwQwvwy)

Comment: Your code works for a custom HTML Form where you can call both functions right from the Attribute "Onclick" but if the form is randomly generated in WordPress then it doesn't work, I even tried to insert an attribute "onclick" and assigned the functions on each checkbox using jquery but that way it doesn't trigger the function and throw the error in console that says "Function doesn't exist".